# UIDocumentInteractionController not working in iPad Simulator (XCode 3.2.3)

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator, uidocumentinteraction

The `UIDocumentInteractionController` appears to be non-functional in iPad Simulator ("iPhone Simulator" version 4.0, shipping with XCode 3.2.3, using iOS Version 3.2).

I have a simple sample code presenting a PDF preview using  `UIDocumentInteractionController`. It works on the device. On iPad `presentPreview` just returns NO, the `UIDocumentInteractionController's` delegate methods are not invoked.

Any hint how to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

Confirming the same behaviour over here: calling `- (BOOL)presentPreviewAnimated:` returns `NO` on the simulator but works on the device. Thanks for pointing this out, I just spent two hours going over my code again and again. Got no solution so far.

Comment: Thank you for confirming. I have filed a bug report with Apple. I have set up a demo project for them.

Comment: Note: The problem is gone in iOS Version 4.2 beta.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had this issue on iOS versions higher than iOS 4.2, even though this was a known bug back in the day.

The issue being that the `UIDocumentInteractionController` would act fine on the device, but in the simulator it would crash. What I discovered was that the problem went away when I managed the memory slightly differently. The difference being, `autoreleasing` in the `DidEndPreview` delegate method. Here's the core of my code :

```
-(void)createPDF
{
    UIDocumentInteractionController *dc;
    //....other code to generate pdf document
    dc = [[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:loadURL] retain];
    dc.delegate = self;

    [dc retain];

    [dc presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
}

//Delegate Methods
- (void)documentInteractionControllerDidEndPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
{
    [controller autorelease];
}
```

Previously I had handled simply created the document controller like a regular modal view and released it after I presented it.

**NOTE : The autorelease is important, you will crash with just a regular release call.**