# iOS Provisioning Portal Link

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, provisioning

I have basically finished developing my App and I wanted to test it on the iPhone, however I wanted to know if this was possible without paying the 99€ fee. I dont plan to release it on the App store in the end...

Thanks,
Anthony

Comment: I'm not sure why this is necessary you have the phone/pad simulator. What's the reason?

Comment: @T9b, some things can only be tested on the device. For example: Core Location significant change notification. There are other things but I cannot remember at the moment.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Test app on iOS device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak)

Comment: @T9b, [UIDocumentInteractionController not working in iPad Simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616981/uidocumentinteractioncontroller-not-working-in-ipad-simulator-xcode-3-2-3) also.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible unless you jailbreak your device.

Answer (score 0):

You could have another developer who has registered, build your app, and then send you a signed developer copy to add to your phone.  You would have to share the code with this developer though.  If it is a one time deal, you can send to me, and I can build it.

Otherwise, Ole is correct, it is not possible.