# Saving text data from iPad application as a note which can be opened from "notes app"?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, core-data

I am developing one iPad application in which I have to store text data as a note in the iPad which can be access then from the default "notes app" of the iPad. Is it possible to store text data as notes?

Please let me know as it is really very critical for my application.

Comment: probably not possible, but you could implement copy&paste for your application

Comment: Hello, I have to implement the notes in my application. I know about the copy and paste functionality and also implemented in one app. But it is critical here to implement the notes functionality as one of my client needs it in application. Can we also save text data in one app can be accessible via different app like "keynotes" or iphone default "note app".

Comment: It is possible for some apps through url schemes or UIDocumentInteractionController. Read about "Implementing Common Application Behaviors" ->  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html

Comment: have u implemented it successfully?I want my native app to save notes to ios app

Comment: @Dhara: Still we haven't implemented completely.

Comment: is it possible to add a note from native app to the ios Notes app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [UIDocumentInteractionController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html), you can send a document/file to another application.  All application on iOS would register with the system the file extension that they can handle.  Apple provides a sample project, [DocInteraction](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DocInteraction/Introduction/Intro.html) demonstrating some of these document interaction. **Please note:** [UIDocumentInteractionController not working in iPad Simulator (XCode 3.2.3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616981/uidocumentinteractioncontroller-not-working-in-ipad-simulator-xcode-3-2-3). The sample project does work on the device.

The Notes.app **doesn't** register any such extension. Please send Apple an [enhancement request](http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html) for this feature.  If enough people makes this request, they might add it into future release.

Comment: Hello, Thank you very much for your answer. Can you please give me some reference in which I can have some working example. And where to store notes file in the application. Can you please send me some reference.

Comment: @AppAspect "reference" doesn't really mean anything in this context but assuming you want an example of how to make a Notes app, simply googling "how make notes app iOS" will get you a plethora of examples like this one: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/.  Anyways, you need to be more clear about what you want- a working example notes app, a working example of document sharing, or something else?